# How do I fix bunifu addapp option from toolbox not crashing itself and exit visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net

I enter feee trail bunifu framework for my c# .net project and I downloaded anything from kimtoo and bunifu from nuget extension and it crashing any time i use especially bunifuapp option from bunifuutils extension.

I expected to work without crashing program

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.